# Spring Batch Job Design -Multiple Readers

Tags: java, spring, replication, batch-processing, spring-batch

I’m struggling with how to design a Spring Batch job.  The overall goal is to retrieve ~20 million records and save them to a sql database.

I’m doing it in two parts.  First I retrieve the 20 million ids of the records I want to retrieve and save those to a file (or DB).  This is a relatively fast operation.  Second, I loop through my file of Ids, taking batches of 2,000, and retrieve their related records from an external service.  I then repeat this, 2,000 Ids at a time, until I’ve retrieved all of the records.  For each batch of 2,000 records I retrieve, I save them to a database.

Some may be asking why I’m doing this in two steps.  I eventual plan to make the second step run in parallel so that I can retrieve batches of 2,000 records in parallel and hopefully greatly speed-up the download. Having the Ids allows me to partition the job into batches.  For now, let’s not worry about parallelism and just focus on how to design a simpler sequential job.

Imagine I already have solved the first problem of saving all of the Ids locally.  They are in a file, one Id per line.  How do I design the steps for the second part?

Here’s what I’m thinking…

Read 2,000 Ids using a flat file reader.  I’ll need an aggregator since I only want to do one query to my external service for each batch of 2K Ids. This is where i’m struggling.  Do I nest a series of readers?  Or can I do ‘reading’ in the processor or writer?

Essentially, my problem is that I want to read lines from a file, aggregate those lines, and then immediately do another ‘read’ to retrieve the respective records. I almost want to chain readers together.

Finally, once I’ve retrieved the records from the external service, I’ll have a List of records.  Which means when they arrive at the Writer, I’ll have a list of lists.  I want a list of objects so that I can use the JdbcItemWriter out of the box.

Thoughts?  Hopefully that makes sense.

Andrew

Comment: I just found this example in the documentation that seems to suggest I should retrieve the full objects (using the ids from the reader) in the processor.  Perhaps I'm taking these interface names a little too literally.  It feels strange to 'read' in the processor.   http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of design and is subjective, but based on the Spring Batch example I found (from SpringSource) and my personal experience, the pattern of doing addtional reading in the processor step is a good solution to this problem.  You can also chain together multiple processors/readers in the 'processor' step.  So, while the names don't exactly match, i find myself doing more and more 'reading' in my processors.

```
[http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to call your external service just once per chunk of 2.000 records, you 'll actually want to do this service call in an `ItemWriter`. That is the standard recommended way to do chunk-level processing.

You can create a custom `ItemWriter<Long>` implementation. It will receive the list of 2.000 IDs as input, and call the external service. The result from the external service should allow you to create a `List<Item>`. Your writer can then simply forward this `List<Item>` to your `JdbcItemWriter<Item>` delegate.